# ARIMA: How to understand performance of the model?

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, forecasting, arima

I am new to use of ARIMA model and after working on it for a couple of days and doing research - I'm not sure how to interpret the performance of my model...

Here is what the `.head()` of my dataframe looks like:

[image: My dataframe for ARIMA]

As you can see it has date at its index with 4 observations/month starting at 06/01/2017. This df has 138 populated *_COST* observations or 155 observations with empty ones for future forecasting.

Now, moving into testing/understanding my df, here is how my rolling mean, rolling std and residual error plots look:

[image: Rolling Mean plot]
[image: Rolling std plot]
[image: Residual errors plot]

Here, I can confirm a couple of things: it has **upwards trend**, **no seasonality**, variance **doesn't** change much, residual errors **are close** to 0.

Finally, after doing all that - I move on to see my ARIMA model forecast...
I decided to use (1,1,0) or differenced first-order autoregressive model as if it was correct choice in my mind (**Please let me know if I'm wrong!**)
Here is the performance of my model; I decided to forecast last 12 weeks and this is what it looks like when I zoom in:
[image: ARIMA plot]

So, looking at this visually I'm not too happy about it...Looking at this on y-axis, because I'm working with $0.## cents it pretty much hits the numbers right.

Is this a **good/bad** performance? Is there some **metrics** to look for (such as precision, accuracy, f-1 or something in that nature as used with other machine learning models?)

Please let me know! All information and help is really appreciated as I'm only starting my professional Data Science journey :)

Comment: I found the way to understand the performance is through `results=model.fit()` and then `print(results.summary())`; that prints a formatted metrics table. Now, the question remains the same how to interpret it...?

Comment: You might find better answer on the quant stack exchange...